# Source one shell script in another gives error in MacOs

Tags: bash, sh

I have the below folder structure

```
--/foo 

  --- /foo/bar 

     ---/foo/bar/bcp_main.sh 
    ---/foo/bar/bcp_core.sh
    ---/foo/bar/second_test.sh
```

Below is my shell script

**second_test.sh**

```
source   $(dirname "$0")/bcp_main.sh
```

**bcp_main.sh**

```
echo "In bcp_main.sh" 
source   $(dirname "$0")/bcp_core.sh
func1
```

**bcp_core.sh**

```
 source   $(dirname "$0")/bcp_query_test.sh

    get_date() {
      date --utc --date="$1" +"%Y-%m-%d"        # +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    }
function func1 {  
   echo "Hello $1"
}
```

The source from second_test.sh is fine but source from bcp_main to bcp_core it says file not found

```
xxxxx@asj177 ~/Desktop/foo
$ ./bar/second_test.sh
In bcp_main.sh 
: No such file or directory./bar/bcp_core.sh
in bcp main
./bar/bcp_main.sh: line 23: func1: command not found
```

I am trying to run this on MacOs , am I missing some thing here . The files have all the permissions .

Comment: source does not change `$0`. Use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` instead.

Comment: Now it gives ./bar/second_test.sh/bcp_main.sh: Not a directory

Comment: Then just strip the erroneous part: `source $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})/bcp_core.sh`

Comment: well I want to call func1 present in bcp_core.sh from bcp_main ,so for that I would need to souce bcp_core in bcp_main

Comment: This works when I reconstruct this on Linux with `a.sh`, `b.sh`, `c.sh`, sourcing it as `a` -> `b` -> `c` and using a function in `a` that is defined in `c` (echo $0). Are you sure `bcp_core.sh` isn't misspelled? Try `ls bar/bcp_core.sh`. Also, use a shebang in every script if you haven't already.

Comment: That error message makes me think that bcp_main.sh has DOS/Windows-style line endings. See: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: "Also, use a shebang in every script if you haven't already" This is not needed if you are sourcing the file. shebang  is used only when you are running the file as `/path/to/file.sh` or `./file.sh`

Answer (score 0):

```
foo
`-- bar\ with\ space
    |-- bcp_core.sh
    |-- bcp_main.sh
    |-- bcp_query_test.sh
    `-- second_test.sh
```

**bcp_core.sh**

```
dir_name=$(cd  "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd -P)
source "${dir_name}"/bcp_query_test.sh

get_date() {
  date --utc --date="$1" +"%Y-%m-%d"        # +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
}

function func1 {
   echo "Hello from bcp_core: $1"
}
```

*bcp_main.sh*

```
dir_name=$(cd  "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd -P)
source "${dir_name}"/bcp_core.sh
func1 "I am passing this"
```

*bcp_query_test.sh*

```
dir_name=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd -P)
echo "Hello from bcp_query_test.sh"
```

*second_test.sh*

```
dir_name=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd -P)
source "${dir_name}"/bcp_main.sh
```

*while inside foo*

```
> source bar\ with\ space/second_test.sh
Hello from bcp_query_test.sh
Hello from bcp_core: I am passing this
> cd bar\ with\ space/
> source second_test.sh
Hello from bcp_query_test.sh
Hello from bcp_core: I am passing this
```

*Why the `dir_name`*

On Linux you can easily get full path of file with `realpath`. macOS doesn't provide `realpath` - you can play with `brew` to get it on board.

This is why we have to play with `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` and `pwd` to get the real path of the script, so we can really know where it is.

*zsh/bash*

Also, note that `zsh` - which is a default shell in macOS, since 10.15.1 - behaves way better in this context.

If you have simple script

```
echo $0
echo $(dirname $0)
```

it will behave differently in `bash` and `zsh`. In `zsh` it makes little bit more sense.

```
# bash
> source bar/simple.sh
bash
.

# zsh
> source bar/simple.sh
bar/simple.sh
bar
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why `dir_name="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd -P)"` is necessary?

Comment: @Bayou - you are right. It's not needed. If we don't care about explicit location of the file, we can skip this part.

Comment: @Oo.oO I updated it but it says 

xxxxx@asj177 ~/Desktop/Foo
$ source bar/second_test.sh
: No such file or directoryop/Foo/bar
: command not found
in bcp main
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
-bash: func1: command not found

Comment: @arpitjoshi - maybe you have spaces somewhere in the path? In that case, make sure to play with `"` around the strings.